# Exponentiel function

Tags: calculus, limits

Choose correct options , more than one may be correct .

Let f be the function defined by  $f(x)=e^{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+x}}-\sqrt{x}}$ we've:

(1)

> $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty$

(2)

> $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$

(3)

> $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=e^{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

(4)

> $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\sqrt{e}$

her graph [image]

I think the correct answer is (3) Indeed :

$$
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+x}}-\sqrt{x}}\\
=& \lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+x}}+\sqrt{x}}}\\
=&\lim_{x\to +\infty}e^{ \dfrac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}+1}}{\sqrt{x}(1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac{ \sqrt{1+x}}{x}})}}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}e^{ \dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}+1}}{(1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac{ \sqrt{1+X}}{x}})}}=e^{\dfrac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}
$$

because of $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{ \sqrt{1+x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{ 1}{x}=0$

- I wonder if there are  some other short ways to calculate that limit ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is (3) *and* (4): $\sqrt{e}$. When dealing with exponent like this one, it is always good to remember that if you let $$L = \lim_{x \to \infty} \exp\Big(\sqrt{x + \sqrt{1+x}} - \sqrt{x}\Big),$$
then $$\begin{align*} \ln L &= \ln \lim_{x \to \infty} \exp\Big(\sqrt{x + \sqrt{1+x}} - \sqrt{x}\Big) =
\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln \exp\Big(\sqrt{x + \sqrt{1+x}} - \sqrt{x}\Big) \end{align*},$$
which is just
$$ \ln L = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x + \sqrt{1+x}} - \sqrt{x}.$$

Comment: Just to point out, $\sqrt{e}=e^{1/2}$

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that, what a shame. It's early morning here... Anyways, I think the method described above could save him some time.

Comment: I agree. +1${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use Taylor series. We have that $$\sqrt{x+a}=\sqrt{x}+{1\over 2}x^{-{1\over 2}}a-...$$ Here $a=\sqrt{x+1}$, so we get $$\lim{\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{2}$$ because the other terms in the Taylor series tend to 0.

Comment: You would be hard pressed to know taylor series without knowing such elementary limits. Just my opinion.

Comment: @ Sabyasachi true but we want to see most short method